# Aligning a Three Column DataFrame by the Order of Another List

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame of a list of names with their coordinates as such:

```
name1 3 100
name2 5 4
name3 7 5
...
name88 100 300
name21 30 40
```

I have another list that is a single column series with only the names in a specific order

```
name3
name10
name2
name6
...
name30
```

Both of these two dataframes have the same number of rows, but I need to reorder the first dataframe so  that the order of names matches that order of the second data frame.

The idea that I had, but haven't been able to implement is to use the pandas groupby function, and use that to group the first dataframe based on the second.

But any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the names column in your dataframe is called `Name` and your other series is called `names`. Then this should do:

```
 df = df.set_index('Name').reindex(index=names).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to simply sort both frames on the index (assuming that the index is the `name`, if not, then set it as the index via `DataFrame.set_index`)

```
DataFrame.sort_index
```

Other approach would be to simply join those two datasets on the index (again, assuming that the `name` is the index).

```
DataFrame.join
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to set a categorical column and sort by that :

assuming that both columns are called names, and you have df1 & df2

```
sorter = pd.Categorical(df1['name'], df2['names'])

df_sort = df1.assign(sort=sorter).sort_values('sort').drop('sort',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df2.merge(df1,on='name')
```

if the name of the columns are different you need:

```
df2.merge(df1,left_on='df2_column_name',
          right_on = 'df1_column_name').drop('df2_column_name',axis=1)
```

**Here is an example**

```
print(df1)
     df1_column_name   v1   v2
0              name1    3  100
1              name2    5    4
2              name3    7    5
3             name88  100  300
4             name21   30   40


print(df2)
     df2_column_name
0              name3
1             name10
2              name2
3              name6
4             name30
5             name21
6             name88
7              name1

df2.merge(df1,left_on='df2_column_name',
          right_on = 'df1_column_name').drop('df2_column_name',axis=1)

  df1_column_name   v1   v2
0           name3    7    5
1           name2    5    4
2          name21   30   40
3          name88  100  300
4           name1    3  100
```

---

Another approach [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
df2.join(df1.set_index('name_df1_column'),on = 'name_df2_column',how = 'right')
```